# Как исправить ошибку AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

> Dasc.append(str(a)) AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute
>   'append'

```
count = 0
Dasc = str([])
while True:
    VOD = print('нажмите : \n 1  если хотите начать работу \n 2 если хотите выйти')
    answer_1 = int(input())
    if answer_1 != 2 and answer_1 != 1:
        print('Число введенно неправельн ')
        continue
    elif answer_1 == 2:
        break
    elif answer_1 == 1:
        if count <= 0:
            print('У вас нет рабоих досок нажмите 1 что бы ее создать')
            answer_2 = int(input())
            if answer_2 != 1:
                print('Вы ввели неправельно число')
                continue
            if answer_2 == 1:
                Dasc = +1
                count += 1
                print('Напешите свои планы')
                a = str(input())
                Dasc.append(str(a))
                print(Dasc)
        if count > 0:
            print(Dasc)
```

Comment: Ну, Dasc у вас — это и в самом деле число, равное единице. У числа действительно не существует никакого append.

Comment: Dasc в вашем случае -- int. А должен быть `[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
count = 0
Dasc = []
while True:
    VOD = print('нажмите : \n 1  если хотите начать работу \n 2 если хотите выйти')
    answer_1 = int(input())
    if answer_1 != 2 and answer_1 != 1:
        print('Число введенно неправельн ')
        continue
    elif answer_1 == 2:
        break
    elif answer_1 == 1:
        if count <= 0:
            print('У вас нет рабоих досок нажмите 1 что бы ее создать')
            answer_2 = int(input())
            if answer_2 != 1:
                print('Вы ввели неправельно число')
                continue
            if answer_2 == 1:
                count += 1
                print('Напешите свои планы')
                a = str(input())
                Dasc.append(str(a))
                print(Dasc)
        if count > 0:
            print(Dasc)
```

Comment: Куски кода без пояснений бесполезны для базы знаний.